# Increment number along with a date on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to increment a cell in a column by 1 to 999. The thing is, it contains both a number and a date:

| Item 1 |
| --- |
| 001/2022 |
| 002/2022 |
| 003/2022 |
| ... |
| 999/2022 |

Is there a way to do this? I assume it's possible to "hard code" the date as a string "2022" and increment the value beside it but, would it be possible to maintain the date format? If anyone can provide both answers and how to tackle them in each way, I'd be much obliged. Sorry if there is a reference to something like that, I just can't find it. I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in any cell with at least 998 open cells below it:

`=ArrayFormula(TEXT(SEQUENCE(999),"000")&"/2022")`

Comment: Thank you Erik, this is perfect.

Comment: Great. Please take a moment to mark this post as "Best Answer." This alerts to contributor community that the issue is fully resolved. And it helps future site visitors more easily find answers that match their own issues and searches. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string by "/", parse & increment the left value and then rejoin the two parts like so:

```
function testIncrement() {
  console.log(increment("005/2021"));
}

function increment(cellValue) {
  const DIVIDER = "/";
  let [a, b] = cellValue.split(DIVIDER)
  return `${Utilities.formatString("%03d", parseInt(a) + 1)}${DIVIDER}${b}`;
}
```

Comment: Sir, it works perfectly. Thank you for your time. How do I populate an X number of cells with it? X being 999. In other words, how do I repeat this script 999 times?